# "Debug error R6010 - abort() has been called" - How to debug?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-2013, callstack

At completely random times during runtime, my program crashes with the error in the title. The error occurs without any user inputs or indication as to why, which makes it difficult to debug. The Call Stack doesn't help either:

```
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f8b7642()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f9e2044()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f9a8c98()    Unknown
msvcp120d.dll!00007ffaa7273340()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f9baf90()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f9aafe2()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffad1633573()    Unknown
msvcp120d.dll!00007ffaa722df29()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f8ba105()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffa9f8ba357()    Unknown
vfbasics.dll!00007ffab17dc729() Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ffacede13d2() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffad15b5444()    Unknown
```

According to the thread list, the error doesn't occur in the main thread, so it might be a multi-threading conflict, but I don't know for sure.

I can't post any code because the program is too big and I don't know which piece of the code is causing the issue.

How can I narrow the problem down?

Comment: Well, are you running it in the debugger?  Set a breakpoint on an exception?

Comment: I am in the debugger. It breaks somewhere in "msvcr120d.amd64.pdb" which I can't access (It's "not loaded"). Neither can I access anything else from the Call Stack.

Comment: Make sure you have the symbols correctly configured and loaded in the debugger.  That should help get a better stack dump. `vfbasics.dll` is part of Application Verifier, so the utilities and configuration associated with App Verifier may help as well.

Comment: @Silverlan What I don't quite understand is why you can't see the function names for a Microsoft debug DLL, especially if you're running this in the debugger.  Are you running a debug version of your app on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed?  Whenever my debug version of the application crashes, I get a call stack every time, and the apps I debug are mutlithreaded.

Comment: In addition, the crashes in the MT apps I've debugged *are* due to race conditions, deadlocks, etc.  Yes MT problems are hard to find, but given that you're running a debug version, it should be just marginally more difficult to discover what is causing the issue than with a non MT app.  Also, I've never needed symbols unless it is a release version -- the VS debugger is quite adequate in solving *debug build" MT issues.  So something, at least to me, seems amiss in your VS setup or how you're really running your app.  Maybe you installed VS and didn't specify to install the runtime source?